# Optimizar código java

Tags: java, array

Buen día.

Hice un **Array** de **Objetos**, y quisiera saber cómo podría optimizarlo.

Mi código es el siguiente

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
    String idPerfil = "R65";
    String idWorkPlace = "0073";
    String workPlace = null;
    String response = null;
    WorkPlace territories = new WorkPlace();
    WorkPlace zones = new WorkPlace();
    WorkPlace offices = new WorkPlace();
    WorkPlace jobs = new WorkPlace();
    WorkPlace employees = new WorkPlace();
    WorkPlace customers = new WorkPlace();


    if(perfilOficina.contains(idPerfil)){
        WorkPlaceDetail workPlaceDetail = srvBranchesV00.getBrachesWorkplace(idWorkPlace);
        ArrayList<WorkPlace> workp = new ArrayList<WorkPlace>();

        territories.setId("Territoriales");
        territories.setName("");
        zones.setId("Zonas");
        zones.setName("");
        offices.setId("Oficinas");
        offices.setName(workPlace);
        jobs.setId("Cargos");
        jobs.setName("");
        employees.setId("Funcionarios");
        employees.setName("");
        customers.setId("Clientes");
        customers.setName("");          
        workp.add(territories);
        workp.add(zones);
        workp.add(offices);
        workp.add(jobs);
        workp.add(employees);
        workp.add(customers);

        response = gson.toJson(workp);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrías crear un método para rellenar los datos de cada objeto, de tal forma que tendrías :

Para el objeto Territorio, Zones, Office, Employees,Costumers y Jobs te valdría con esto :

```
//asumiendo que son datos String

void setDatos(String id,String name){
     setId("Territoriales");
     setName("");
}
```

Para el objeto Workp :

```
void addDatos(Territories territories,Zones zones,Offices offices, Jobs jobs, Employees employees, Costumers costumers){

        add(territories);
        add(zones);
        add(offices);
        add(jobs);
        add(employees);
        add(customers);
}
```

Quedando tu código mucho más limpio:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
    String idPerfil = "R65";
    String idWorkPlace = "0073";
    String workPlace = null;
    String response = null;
    WorkPlace territories = new WorkPlace();
    WorkPlace zones = new WorkPlace();
    WorkPlace offices = new WorkPlace();
    WorkPlace jobs = new WorkPlace();
    WorkPlace employees = new WorkPlace();
    WorkPlace customers = new WorkPlace();


    if(perfilOficina.contains(idPerfil)){
        WorkPlaceDetail workPlaceDetail = srvBranchesV00.getBrachesWorkplace(idWorkPlace);
        ArrayList<WorkPlace> workp = new ArrayList<WorkPlace>();


        territories.setDatos("Territoriales","");
        zones.setDatos("Zonas","");
        offices.setDatos("Oficinas",workPlace);
        jobs.setDatos("Cargos","");
        employees.setDatos("Funcionarios","");
        customers.setDatos("Clientes","");

        workp.addDAtos(territories,zones,offices,jobs,employees,customers);

        response = gson.toJson(workp);
```